# Python Script to Create Table Using Data Driven Pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcpy, data-driven-pages

I am trying to convert some python script to display a table (based on a dbf) of features located within a specific data driven page. So far, I have the script successfully able to refresh the map to the specific table, but it does not update the table.

I have it set-up as three text boxes that should be updated with three specific fields when the user runs the script from ArcToolbox.

Any suggestions on why my table is not updating?

```
import arcpy, sys, os

#Reference current MXD
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")

#Get input parameter
Name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

#Reference  data frames
mapatlasDF = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
locatorDF = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Locator Map")[0]

#Reference appropriate layers
atlasLyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "PinalCreekMapAtlas_HalfMile", mapatlasDF)[0]
locatorLyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Locator Map", locatorDF)[0]
atlasoutlineLyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Map Atlas Outline", locatorDF)[0]

#Reference layout elements by calling ListLayoutElements 
for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd):
  if elm.name =="Table1Column1": tab1Col1Txt = elm
  if elm.name =="Table1Column2": tab1Col2Txt = elm
  if elm.name =="Table1Column3": tab1Col3Txt = elm

#Reference the Data Driven Page object
ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages

#Set the current page to be the one selected in the script tool
arcpy.AddMessage(Name)

pageID = mxd.dataDrivenPages.getPageIDFromName(str(Name))
mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageID

#Set the appropriate definition queries
atlasLyr.definitionQuery = "Name = '" + Name +  "'"
locatorLyr.definitionQuery = "Name = '" + Name +  "'"
atlasoutlineLyr.definitionQuery = "Name <> '" + Name +  "'"

#Update Sheet Index data frame
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(locatorLyr, "NEW_SELECTION", "\"Name\" = '" + Name + "'")
locatorDF.panToExtent(locatorLyr.getSelectedExtent())

#Reference Affected Parcels table and select appropriate records
parcelTable = arcpy.mapping.ListTableViews(mxd, "AffectedParcels")[0]

#Build query and create search cursor to loop through rows
parcelFieldValue = "Page " + Name
queryExp = "\"MapPage\" = '" + parcelFieldValue + "'"  #e.g., "MapPage" = 'Page 01'
parcelRows = arcpy.SearchCursor(parcelTable.dataSource, queryExp)

#Clear all table text values
tab1Col1Txt.text = " "; tab1Col2Txt.text = " "; tab1Col3Txt.text = " "

#iteate through each row, update appropiate text
count = 0
for row in parcelRows:
  if count < 30: #Table1 - static position
    tab1Col1Txt.text = tab1Col1Txt.text + row.getValue("OwnerName") +"\n"
    tab1Col2Txt.text = tab1Col2Txt.text + row.getValue("APN") + "\n"
    tab1Col3Txt.text = tab1Col3Txt.text + row.getValue("LengthTrail") + "\n"
  if count ==30:  
    arcpy.AddMessage("Table Overflow") #The code could be reworked to show the last 90 records
  count = count + 1

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.AddMessage("PROCESS COMPLETED")
```

Comment: I'd start by trying to cut down your script to a simpler example. Are the objects being returned by `ListLayoutElements` of type `TextElement`? Can you update a single text value in the script, without any of the other code?

Comment: as scw said, are the elements actually being returned? I would add arcpy.AddMessage("Found Table1Column1") in each if statment and then add arcpy.AddMessage(tab1Col1Txt.text + tab1Col2Txt.text + tab1Col3Txt.text) in the if count < 30 area. This will give a better idea of where the problem is occurring.

Comment: From the code is not clear where are the tab1Col1Txt, tab1Col2Txt and tab1Col3Txt objects are defined. First try to verify what gets returned by the row.getValue part

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps these examples could help:

[DDP with Dynamic Tables And Graphs 10.1_v1](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=3a525b986b774a3f9cbbd8daf2435852)

This sample demonstrates how the arcpy.mapping API is used to extend the capabilities of Data Driven Pages (DDP) to produce a map series truly dynamic tables and graphs

[arcpy.mapping Map Book with Dynamic Graphic Tables](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=8C8E6EB6-1422-2418-A0B8-6AA61BF57894)

This project incorporates Data Driven Pages and arcpy.mapping to build a map series that includes dynamic graphic tables.

Comment: Can you provide more content in your answers?  Link only answers are not preferred since the link may change over time.